# The value given by cpu_time does not change over little time

Tags: fortran

I want to check how much time does it take the computer to compute a function. To do this I wanted to compare the values given by the cpu_time subroutine before and after calling my function. To my surprise, the value before and after was the same as if it took zero time to perform the function. To check it, I created a simple piece of code

```
call cpu_time(time)
write(*,*) time
do i=1,10000
 !simple math equation here
end do
call cpu_time(time)
write(*,*) time
```

And after running the program the value printed before and after the loop was exaclty the same. My guess is that the system clock is not precise enough to dinstinguish such a little changes, but does it really make sense? All in all I don't know how to measure the time needed for executing my function without this working properly.

Comment: Before you conclude your system clock lacks sufficient precision (which may be the case) make sure that the operations you time are (a) sufficiently burdensome on a modern CPU to take a measurable fraction of a second (O(10^4) simple mathematical operations probably doesn't qualify) and (b) not optimised away entirely by a smart compiler which sees that the code doesn't use the results of the operations in the loop.

Comment: Show some real testable example. And use at least double precision time variable.

Comment: Cpu_time tick rate of 64 or 128 hz is typical.  If you want elapsed time, system_clock with int64 arguments is more satisfactory, except for ifort windows, where omp_get_wtime or Mpi_wtime may give the resolution of query_performance api.